# Liquibase doesn't update in-memory h2 database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, liquibase

I set up a simple spring-boot-application, and wanted to include liquibase for database migrations. I defined a `master.xml`, which consists of a single reference to another file. This file defines a changeset for creating a table with the name `test`. Until this point everything seems to be fine. However, after tryining to apply the changes by executing `liquibase:update`, through the `liquibase-maven-plugin`, my `test` table won't be created.

Did i do something wrong in my `application-properties` or in the `pom.xml`? Any hints would help :)

Here the code:

`master.xml`:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="migration/0000-init-schema.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

`0000-init-schema.xml`:

```
<databaseChangeLog logicalFilePath="db.changelog-1.0.xml" xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
    <changeSet author="kezersa72274" id="2020-01-01-1">
        <comment>Create table test.</comment>

        <createTable tableName="test">
            <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.digiplan</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>digiplan-backend</name>
    <description>Digiplan-Backend</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>
                        /src/main/resources/master.xml
                    </changeLogFile>
                    <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:mem:digiplan</url>
                    <username>sa</username>
                    <password></password>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.name=digiplan
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:digiplan
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

`BackendApplication.java`

```
package de.digiplan.backend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`BackendApplicationTests.java`:

```
package de.digiplan.backend;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public final class BackendApplicationTests {
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

The logs on calling `liquibase:update`:

```
"/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/saltukkezer/digiplan-backend "-Dmaven.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=64094:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.2 org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< de.digiplan:backend >-------------------------
[INFO] Building digiplan-backend 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update (default-cli) @ backend ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Starting Liquibase at Sun, 22 Dec 2019 15:39:29 CET (version 3.6.2 built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09)
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:h2:mem:digiplan
[INFO] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
[INFO] CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))
[INFO] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
[INFO] DELETE FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
[INFO] INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, FALSE)
[INFO] SELECT LOCKED FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
[INFO] Successfully acquired change log lock
[INFO] Creating database history table with name: DATABASECHANGELOG
[INFO] CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10))
[INFO] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATABASECHANGELOG
[INFO] Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
[INFO] SELECT * FROM DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
[INFO] SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
[INFO] CREATE TABLE test (id BIGINT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY (id))
[INFO] Table test created
[INFO] ChangeSet db.changelog-1.0.xml::2020-01-01-1::kezersa72274 ran successfully in 1ms
[INFO] SELECT MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM DATABASECHANGELOG
[INFO] INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('2020-01-01-1', 'kezersa72274', 'db.changelog-1.0.xml', NOW(), 1, '8:86a27a6c6ac5d44947040cf6a87f248c', 'createTable tableName=test', 'Create table test.', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.6.2', '7025570948')
[INFO] Successfully released change log lock
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.600 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-22T15:39:30+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-> [What the database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quXu8.png)

Comment: spring.datasource.password=password but you put  <password></password>

Comment: @ZainElabidine From where do you know that the password needs to be "password"? I tried it, and it doesn't seem to work that way, either. I thought that the default configuration of spring is `user=sa` and `password=`(empty).

Comment: from your application.properties

Comment: spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

Comment: Ah, okay now i got it, sorry. But unfortunately it's still not working. :/

Comment: Liquibase is creating your table as shown in the logs but since the database is in-memory it is not preserving the created database after the application exit.So if you need to preserve the database then export it to a file or use another RDBMS. For these lines it is evident "INFO] CREATE TABLE test (id BIGINT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY (id))
[INFO] Table test created"

Comment: @user06062019 That's also what i suspected (i already switched to using a file instead of in-memory), but if now e.g. i open my application and run liquibase (while the application is still running), shouldn't it then be possible to see the changes introduced in the DB?

Comment: Yes if your application is running and if you are trying to query the in-memory database it should have the table there.

Comment: But that's not working also, unfortunately. :/

Comment: Couple of things to change ...firstly change the database url to <url>jdbc:h2:file:~/test</url> in maven plugin.This will save your database to the file system.After that in application properties add these properties spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;IFEXISTS=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;
spring.datasource.name=test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.initialize=false    I have tested and it is working for me .Let me know if you need code for this

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort! I already switched to file instead of in-memory, and it works perfectly fine (with my configuration presented in the post). The thing that just confused me is that i couldn't update anything through liquibase after starting the application. But that's probably because i used an in-memory database, like you already described in your comment.

Another question that arised after using a file-based db was that now everything works, but i can only access the database through the h2-console AND NOT through the database interface in IntelliJ or DBeaver. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

From the logs it is apparent that liquibase has run and created the database but since it is H2 and is configured as in-memory the changes will be lost once the liquibase update is over.If you have used other RDBMS,these changes would have preserved.

In order to make H2 work with your project,you need to make H2 to persist the database on the file system by changing the URL in the liquibase maven plugin.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
         <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
            <changeLogFile>
               /src/main/resources/master.xml
            </changeLogFile>
            <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:h2:file:~/digiplan</url>
            <username>sa</username>
            <password></password>
         </configuration>
         <version>3.6.2</version>
      </plugin>
```

Also change the spring.datasource.url property from

jdbc:h2:mem:digiplan to  jdbc:h2:file:~/digiplan

Answer (score -1):

In your example, you don't ask spring-boot to launch liquibase at startup. Add:

```yaml
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml`
```

in your application.

After that, you can remove the configuration of database from your pom.xml because liquibase will use spring configuration for databse.

NB: in yml format, the property for class name is 'driver-class-name'

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why, as i thought that it defaults to the settings defined in the `application.properties`, but for some reason your suggested changes don't work.

I get this error:
`Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.2:update (default-cli) on project backend: The database URL has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file.`

Maybe it's because liquibase can be run separately from the spring project, and that's why it requires own properties?

Comment: once again, remove liquibase-maven-plugin from your pom.xml :)